# Closed form for a multilinear skew-symmetric map applied in sums?

Tags: linear-algebra, summation, closed-form, skew-mapping

Suppose $\varepsilon$ is a multilinear skew-symmetric function of its arguments with vales in $\mathbb R$. Is it true that:

$$\varepsilon(a_1+\theta_1, \ldots, a_p+\theta_p)=\varepsilon(a_1, \ldots, a_p)+\\
+(-1)^p\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}\sum_{1\leq j_1<\ldots< j_i\leq p} (-1)^{j_1+\ldots +j_i} \varepsilon(a_1, \ldots, \widehat{a_{j_1}}, \ldots, \widehat{a_{j_i}}, \ldots, a_p, \theta_{j_1}, \ldots, \theta_{j_i})\\
+\varepsilon(\theta_1, \ldots, \theta_p)$$ where the hats means omission?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you elaborate on where you run into difficulty when you try to check this formula?

Comment: The sign on the term $\epsilon(a_1,\ldots,\widehat{a_{j_1}},\ldots,\widehat{a_{j_i}},\ldots,a_p,\theta_{j_1},\ldots,\theta_{j_i}$ should be $(-1)^\sigma$, with $\sigma = \sum_{k=1}^i p-k+1-j_{i+1-k} = ip + i -\frac{i(i+1)}{2} -\sum_{i=1}^k j_i $.

Comment: Taking the sign mod $2$, the claim becomes $ip+i+\frac{i(i+1)}{2} \equiv p+i+1$ when $i> 0$, and $ip+i+\frac{i(i+1)}{2} \equiv 0$ when $i=0$. The last claim is certainly true. The first is equivalent to $(i-1)p +\frac{i(i+1)}{2} \equiv 1$ for all $0<i\le p$, and all $p>0$. This seems false. E.g., take $p$ even, $i=4$. Then we get $0\equiv 1$.

Comment: But perhaps my calculations are wrong. These are just comments, not an answer.

Comment: As a matter of fact, the formula is a conjecture. I'll try to fix the signs..

Comment: @jgon I fixed the signs. Do you agree with the formula now?

Comment: Is it true for $\epsilon(x,y)=x -y$?

Comment: @ancientmathematician your map is not bilinear..

Comment: The question has changed.

Comment: I had missed the word multilinear.

Comment: @jgon the sign shouldn't be $ip-(j_1+\ldots+j_i)- \frac{i(i-1)}{2}$?

Comment: @PtF, I'm pretty sure that my sign is correct. You have to commute $\theta_{j_{i+1-k}}$ past $p-j_{i+1-k} - (k-1)$ things.

Comment: The first time $\varepsilon(a_1, \ldots, b_{j_1}, \ldots, b_{j_i}, \ldots, a_p)=(-1)^{p-j_1}\varepsilon(a_1, \ldots, b_{j_2}, \ldots, b_{j_i}, \ldots, a_p, b_{j_1})$. The next time you will have to commute $b_{j_2}$ past $p-j_2+1$. The last time you will have to commute $b_{j_i}$ past $p-j_i+(i-1)$, hence the sign should be $ip-(j_1+\ldots+j_i)+(1+\ldots+(i-1))=ip-(j_1+\ldots+j_i)+ \frac{i(i-1)}{2}$, nope?

Comment: As a matter of fact, $i-\frac{i(i+1)}{2}= \frac{2i-i^2-i}{2}=\frac{i-i^2}{2}=-\frac{i(i-1)}{2}$ so our signs are identical for $(-1)^{-\frac{i(i-1)}{2}}=(-1)^{\frac{i(i-1)}{2}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Discussing with @jgon we got to the same conclusion, therefore I assume we have the right answer which I'm posting just in case someone else needs in the future.

In order to find the correct expression, it suffices to find $\sigma$ in:

$$\varepsilon(a_1, \ldots, a_{j_1-1}, b_{j_1}, a_{j_1+1}, \ldots, a_{j_i-1}, b_{j_i}, a_{j_i+1}, \ldots, a_p)=(-1)^\sigma \varepsilon(a_1, \ldots, \widehat{a_{j_1}}, \ldots, \widehat{a_{j_i}}, \ldots, a_p, b_{j_1}, \ldots, b_{j_i}).$$

Let us focus on $b_{j_1}$. For it to appear beside $a_p$ on the RHS of the above equality, it will have to go past $p-j_{1}$ positions. Therefore:

$$\varepsilon(a_1, \ldots, a_{j_1-1}, a_{j_1+1}, \ldots, a_{j_i-1}, b_{j_i}, a_{j_i+1}, \ldots, a_p)\\
= (-1)^{p-j_1} \varepsilon(a_1, \ldots, \widehat{a_{j_1}}, \ldots, a_{j_i-1}, b_{j_i}, a_{j_i+1}, \ldots, a_p, b_{j_1}).$$

Now we focus on $b_{j_2}$. It will have to go past $p-j_2+1$ places, therefore:

$$\varepsilon(a_1, \ldots, a_{j_1-1}, a_{j_1+1}, \ldots, a_{j_2-1}, b_{j_2}, a_{j_2+1}, \ldots, a_{j_i-1}, b_{j_i}, a_{j_i+1}, \ldots, a_p)\\= (-1)^{p-j_1} (-1)^{p-j_2+1} \varepsilon(a_1, \ldots, \widehat{a_{j_1}}, \ldots, \widehat{a_{j_2}}, \ldots, a_{j_i-1}, b_{j_i}, a_{j_i+1}, \ldots, a_p, b_{j_1}, b_{j_2}). $$

The last $b_{j_i}$ will have to go past $p-j_i+(1+\ldots+(i-1))$ places, therefore:

$$\varepsilon(a_1, \ldots, a_{j_1-1}, a_{j_1+1}, \ldots, a_{j_i-1},b_{j_i}, a_{j_i+1}, \ldots, a_p)=(-1)^{p-j_1}(-1)^{p-j_2+1}\cdots (-1)^{p-j_i+(i-1)}\varepsilon(a_1, \ldots, \widehat{a_{j_1}}, \ldots, \widehat{a_{j_i}}, \ldots, a_p, b_{j_1}, \ldots, b_{j_i}).$$ Now notice:

$$(-1)^{p-j_1}(-1)^{p-j_2+1}\cdots (-1)^{p-j_i+(i-1)}=(-1)^{pi-(j_1+\ldots+j_i)+ \frac{i(i-1)}{2}}$$ where I used the standard fact $$1+\ldots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$ with $n=i-1$. Therefore:

$$\varepsilon(a_1+b_1, \ldots, a_p+b_p)= \varepsilon(a_1, \ldots, a_p)\\
+ \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} (-1)^{ip} (-1)^{i(i-1)/2} \sum_{1\leq j_1<\ldots<j_i\leq p} (-1)^{j_1+\ldots+j_i} \varepsilon(a_1, \ldots, \widehat{a_{j_1}}, \ldots, \widehat{a_{j_i}}, \ldots, a_p, b_{j_1}, \ldots, b_{j_p})\\
+\varepsilon(b_1, \ldots, b_p).$$ I know this can be written in a straightforward manner using shuffles, but I wanted to avoid that.